# Why am I getting an implicit declaration error for a predefined gtk function?

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to read text in from a file and insert that text into a text box.

This is the code I am using.

```
FILE *infile;
GdkFont *fixed_font;
infile = fopen("text.txt", "r");



fixed_font = gdk_font_load ("-misc-fixed-medium-r-*-*-*-140-*-*-*-*-*-*");

if (infile) {
char buffer[1024];
int nchars;

while (1)
  {
    nchars = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, infile);
    gtk_text_insert(view, fixed_font, NULL, NULL, buffer, nchars);

    if (nchars < 1024)
      break;
  }

fclose (infile);
```

These are my includes

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtktext.h>
```

When I compile I get this warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_text_insert’
```

I have read on this forum and others that implicit declaration errors come from using functions before they are declared.  However, `gtk_text_insert()` is included in the header file so how can this be implicit?

I am using the following software:

```
  gtk version 2.20.1

  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GtkText is deprecated and unsupported. It is known to be buggy. **To use it, you must define the symbol `GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN` prior to including the GTK+ header files.** Use GtkTextView instead.

From https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkText.html