# Get form entered values on gtk C

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gtk4

i have a program on gtk written on C, i declared a form inside a modal that it been displayed after clicking a button, i want to get the entered information from the form :

Form decalaration:

```
void on_button_add_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWindow *parent_window = GTK_WINDOW(user_data);

    // Create a new modal window
    GtkWidget *modal_window = gtk_window_new();
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), "Add Item");
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), parent_window);
    gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), TRUE);

    // Create a box to hold the labels and entries
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), box);

    // Set padding around the box container
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(box, 40);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end(box, 40);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top(box, 40);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(box, 40);

    // Create and add the first name label and entry to the box
    GtkWidget *first_name_label = gtk_label_new("Enter first name:");
    GtkWidget *first_name_entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), first_name_label);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), first_name_entry);

    // Create and add the second name label and entry to the box
    GtkWidget *second_name_label = gtk_label_new("Enter second name:");
    GtkWidget *second_name_entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), second_name_label);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), second_name_entry);

    // Create and add the ID label and entry to the box
    GtkWidget *id_label = gtk_label_new("Enter ID (numbers only):");
    GtkWidget *id_entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_entry_set_input_purpose(GTK_ENTRY(id_entry), GTK_INPUT_PURPOSE_DIGITS); // Sets input method for ID to accept only numbers
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), id_label);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), id_entry);

    // Create and add "Confirm" button to the box
    GtkWidget *confirm_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Confirm");
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), confirm_button);

    // Present the modal window
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window));
}
```

i added on confirm signal and try to get the information from it using gtk_entery_get_text:

```
void on_confirm_button_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    // Retrieve the modal window and input fields from user_data
    GtkWidget *modal_window = gtk_widget_get_ancestor(GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_TYPE_WINDOW);
    GtkWidget *first_name_entry = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(modal_window), "first_name_entry");
    GtkWidget *second_name_entry = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(modal_window), "second_name_entry");
    GtkWidget *id_entry = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(modal_window), "id_entry");

    // Get text from the input fields
    const char *first_name = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(first_name_entry));
    const char *second_name = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(second_name_entry));
    const char *id = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(id_entry));

    // // Save data to the array
    if (people_count < 100) {  // Ensure we don't exceed the array size
        strncpy(people[people_count].first_name, first_name, sizeof(people[people_count].first_name) - 1);
        strncpy(people[people_count].second_name, second_name, sizeof(people[people_count].second_name) - 1);
        strncpy(people[people_count].id, id, sizeof(people[people_count].id) - 1);
        people_count++;
    }

    // // Close the modal window
    gtk_window_close(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window));

    // // Print the contents of the array to the terminal
    for (int i = 0; i < people_count; i++) {
        printf("Person %d: %s %s, ID: %s\n", i + 1, people[i].first_name, people[i].second_name, people[i].id);
    }
}
```

it didnt work and i faced a lot of compilation errors:
[compilation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYxVq.png)

the compilation command i used: gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o app tov.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk4 )

how to solve this problem

Comment: @gregspears which header would declare `gtk_entry_get_tabs` but not `gtk_entry_get_text`? If you see more indicators for missing header, you could tell the OP what these are.  Additionally, the linker also can't find the function. Clearly not just a missing header. Was it removed in gtk4?

Comment: Please show your error message (including build command) as text in your queston, not as picture of text.

Comment: @Gerhardh -- of course, you are right.  The errors *resembled* the same we see when an `#include` file is omitted, but it did Not occur to me (as you pointed out), that perhaps the function is deprecated.  *If* that is the issue then *maybe* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369678/why-am-i-getting-an-implicit-declaration-error-for-a-predefined-gtk-function) will help.  In short, it provides a workaround whereby one defines `GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN` prior to including the GTK header files when these compile errors are seen.  Thank you for your mentoring.

Comment: @Gerhardh i added the compilation command. i think its not about the header declaration i declared #include <gtk/gtk.h> on top of the file 
Additionally, when i remove that part of the code (when using the gtk_entery_get_text(), the code works completly fine, so the error is related with something else

Comment: Did you try what grep spears suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you didn't provide a complete listing. Otherwise, I could have returned a working version.
So just a few hints:
The gtk_entry_get_text function no longer exists in GTK4. Instead, you should do as I did in the answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77697643/22768315 I have described. (Use buffer)
Presumably, there is also a problem with the validity of the variables within the different functions in the script you showed. Again, the following answers can help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634992/22768315

Regards.