# GTK Modal Form Input Verification Issue

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I'm working on a GTK4 application using Glade for UI design. The main issue I'm facing is that, when attempting to verify input values entered in a modal form, the variables holding these inputs appear to be empty.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

Signal Handler for "Add" Button:

```
void on_button_add_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Add button was clicked\n");

    // Declare the modal and confirm button locally
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("design.glade");
    GtkWidget *modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "add_item_modal"));
    GtkWidget *confirm_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_confirm"));

    // Set parent window for the modal
    GtkWindow *parent_window = GTK_WINDOW(user_data);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), parent_window);

    // Set the modal window for the "Confirm" button
    g_signal_connect(confirm_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_confirm_clicked), modal_window);

    // Present the modal window using gtk_window_present
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window));

    // Release the builder
    g_object_unref(builder);
}
```

Signal Handler for "Confirm" Button:

```
void on_button_confirm_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(user_data);
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("design.glade");

    GtkWidget *first_name_entry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "first_name_entry"));
    GtkWidget *second_name_entry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "second_name_entry"));
    GtkWidget *id_entry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "id_entry"));

    const char *first_name = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(first_name_entry));
    const char *second_name = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(second_name_entry));
    const char *id_text = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(id_entry));

    if (strlen(first_name) == 0)
    {
        printf("input empty ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("First Name: %s\n", first_name);
    }
}
```

- The modal form opens correctly.
- Input values are entered in the form.
- However, when attempting to access and verify these values in the on_button_confirm_clicked handler, the variables appear empty.

Why are the variables holding the input values empty?
How can I properly retrieve and verify the input values from the modal form?
Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the answer to the question [Get form entered values on gtk C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77771809/22768315)  the problem is within the scope of the variables/objects. I have shown a possible solution for first_name_entry in the script below.

```
// Signal handler for the "Add" button
void on_button_add_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *confirm_button;
    GtkWidget *first_name_entry;  // new
    printf("Add button was clicked\n");
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("design.glade");
    GtkWidget *modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "add_item_modal"));

// Set parent window for the modal
GtkWindow *parent_window = GTK_WINDOW(user_data);
gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), parent_window);

first_name_entry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "first_name_entry")); //new
confirm_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_confirm"));
g_signal_connect(confirm_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_confirm_clicked), first_name_entry); // changed


// Present the modal window using gtk_window_present
gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window));
g_object_unref(builder);
}

void on_button_confirm_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *first_name_entry = GTK_WIDGET(user_data);  

    const char *first_name = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(first_name_entry));
   // const char *second_name =   gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(second_name));
   // const char *id_text = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(id_entry));

    if (first_name == NULL) // new
    {
        printf("input empty ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("First Name: %s\n", first_name);
    }
    // Additional logic...
}
```

To take over all the elements of the modal window, you could find a solution like the one in the answer to [unable to add label to box by the click of a button gtk4 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77621085/22768315) use.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. -